# If I have vim open in two terminals, how can I share the copy/paste buffer?

Tags: vim

I want to `yy` a line from one instance of vim running in one terminal emulator, and `p` that line into another instance of vim running in another terminal emulator. Possible? Is there a special setting to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a system clipboard which you can use to share data not only between multiple terminals, but also using `shift + insert` in GUI application.

First of all, check if system clipboard is enabled for your vim installation

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
```

if you see `+clipboard` you are good to continue, otherwise, follow [this page](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard) to enable the system clipboard.

Once the system clipboard is enabled, you can copy line via `"+yy` into `+` buffer which is a system clipboard, and paste it in another terminal with vim with `"+p` command.

Comment: One can also use the `*` register istead of `+`.

Comment: You are right, afaik on Windows, they are synonyms, while on Linux different, `+` is for copy buffer, while `*` is for mouse selection buffer.

Comment: Not on Linux — on any POSIX OS with XWindows. `vim` is required to be linked with X libraries (`gvim` is always ok, but terminal `vim` is not always).

Answer (score 1):

You can instead:
`Esc` for canceling all modes
`:r! cat file.txt` all content of file.txt pasts in your file, but if you want paste for example from 5 to 11 lines of file then
`:r! sed -n 5,11p file.txt`